# replace current_page_item class in menu

Tags: menus, callbacks

I want to replace below class with `active` class in menu:

```
.current-menu-item
```

and

```
.current_page_item
```

I am already using a menu callback which add a class `dropdown` in child menu:

```
class foundation_navigation extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

function start_lvl(&$output, $depth) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    $output .= "\n$indent<a href=\"#\" class=\"dropdown-toggle\"><span> </span></a><ul class=\"dropdown\">\n";
}

function display_element( $element, &$children_elements, $max_depth, $depth=0, $args, &$output ) {
    $id_field = $this->db_fields['id'];
    if ( !empty( $children_elements[ $element->$id_field ] ) ) {
        $element->classes[] = 'has-dropdown';
    }
        Walker_Nav_Menu::display_element( $element, $children_elements, $max_depth, $depth, $args, $output );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this line at top of your display element function:

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'add_active_class_to_nav_menu');
```

Add this line at bottom of your display element function:

```
remove_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'add_active_class_to_nav_menu');
```

Add this function somewhere in your themes `functions.php`:

```
function add_active_class_to_nav_menu($classes) {
    if (in_array('current-menu-item', $classes, true) || in_array('current_page_item', $classes, true)) {
        $classes = array_diff($classes, array('current-menu-item', 'current_page_item', 'active'));
        $classes[] = 'active';
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

Comment: why using `remove_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'add_active_class_to_nav_menu');` Only works when I dont use remove filter.

Comment: `remove_filter` is to remove the functionality of replacing classes. I added it so that this doesn't affect any of the other menus you might have on your site. As for it not working, make sure you're adding `remove_filter` line at the *bottom* of the function

Comment: thanks for explain. I want to override all menu in my site. Thanks

Comment: In that case, you don't need `remove_filter`. Also copy the `add_filter` line from inside the `display_element` function to directly in your `functions.php`, otherwise it will not work in case you decide not to use the walker in future.

Answer (score 0):

Search for current_page_item.  I found it four times total in post-template.php and nav-menu-template.php.  Then replace it with **active**.

Comment: Please do not encourage people to hack Core files. It leads to nothing but heartache.